# JavaFX wait for enter

Tags: javafx, listener, keylistener

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is something like to a text-based RPG using JavaFX. Right now, to display some text, I've got this:

```
final IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.millis(70),
                    event -> {
                        if (i.get() > info.getText().length()) {
                            timeline.stop();
                        } else {
                            text.setText(info.getText().substring(0, i.get()));
                            i.set(i.get() + 1);
                        }
                    });
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
            timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.play();
            timeline.setOnFinished(a -> {
                hb_start.getChildren().clear();
                hb_start.getChildren().addAll(start_left,start_right);
                hb_start.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            });
```

Because the length of the animation depends on the size of the text, the cyclecount is set to indefinite. Unless there's some other way I'm missing to make the animation play once and then stop, I'd like it so that when you press enter (or some other key that I decide on later) for it to call `timeline.stop();` but I can't figure out how to add any sort of listener. Trying to implement `keyListener`seems to come with all sorts of stuff that I don't need, and it also doesn't work with a `TextField`, and instead wants a `JTextField`, which might be fine, except that I don't have a clue how to do anything with Swing.

Currently, the text is being displayed in a`TextFlow` from the text of `Text`. I'm assuming the listener would be added to the `TextFlow`, or even the scene itself, honestly, I'm at a loss for what to do. It sounds simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyListener` is a AWT class, not a JavaFX class. Unless you're embedding a Swing component in your JavaFX application or a JavaFX node in a Swing application, you should use JavaFX's equivalent `EventHandler<KeyEvent>` instead. Furthermore there is no need to include a `TextField` (or Swing's `JTextField`) in your application just for the sake of receiving key events. You could add the listener directly to the `Scene`:

```
final KeyCode stopKey = KeyCode.ENTER;
EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler = event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == stopKey) {
        timeline.stop();
    }
};
scene.setOnKeyPressed(handler);
```

Note that events can be consumed by nodes before they reach the scene, e.g. by a `TextField` that has the focus. In this case you could make sure you get the event by registering a the listener as a event filter instead:

```
// scene.setOnKeyPressed(handler);
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler);
```